# set image to category programmatically in Magento

Tags: image, magento, set, categories

I try to add a category in magento by this code:

```
$_cat = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$_cat->setName($nom);
$_cat->setUrlKey($nom);
$_cat->setIsActive(1);

$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
$_cat->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());             
$mediaAttribute = array ('thumbnail');
$_cat->addImageToMediaGallery($other_file, $mediaAttribute, true, false);
$_cat->save();
```

its works, but the image is not inserted, I need to know what is the correct code to insert the category image programmatically,

Thanks u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I solved it , to add additionnel datas write :

```
$data['display_mode'] = 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE';
$data['page_layout'] = 'one_column';
$data['thumbnail'] = $path; // path to your image 
$_cat->addData($data);
```

then put your image in YOUR_MAGENTO/media/catalog/category/NAME_OF_IMAGE.jpg

Cheers.

Comment: here what do you mean by $path. Is it a full path of my directory where actual image is stored for eg: D:images/category/T1.jpg or just an image name for eg: T1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```
$newCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$newCategory->setName('Category name');
$newCategory->setUrlKey('category-name');
$newCategory->setIsActive(1);

$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
$newCategory->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());             
$newCategory->setImage('file_name.jpg');
$newCategory->save();
```

Make sure your category image 'file_name.jpg' is uploaded to media/catalog/category/file_name.jpg

BTW, any answer mentioning "addImageToMediaGallery" is wrong. This method only exist for product, not for category.
Also the correct attribute name for category is "image" not "thumbnail".

Answer (score 0):

You could have also done to make it look cleaner and more readable:

```
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);

$newCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$newCategory->setName($nom);
$newCategory->setUrlKey($nom);
$newCategory->setIsActive(1);    
$newCategory->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
$newCategory->addImageToMediaGallery($other_file, array ('thumbnail'), true, false);
$newCategory->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE');
$newCategory->setPageLayout('one_column');
$newCategory->setThumbnail($path); // path to your image 
$newCategory->save();
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

ElGabbu, in your code i get this error :

```
   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::addImageToMedia                                                 Gallery(Array
    (
        [0] => image.jpg
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => thumbnail
            )

        [2] => 1
        [3] =>
    )
    )' in /home/www/magento/lib/Varien/Object.php:569
```

that my code who worked for me :

```
$_cat = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$_cat->setName($nom);
$_cat->setUrlKey($nom);
$_cat->setIsActive(1);
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
$_cat->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());     
$_cat->setIsAnchor(1);
$data['display_mode'] = 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE';
$data['page_layout'] = 'one_column';
$data['thumbnail'] = $path;
$_cat->addData($data);                                          
$_cat->save();
```

Comment: I have look for the function addImageToMediaGallery and it is only available in the product model Mage_Catalog_Model_Product thus the error being display.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snipped based on `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Image` to copy the image from external path to the thumbnail property including a _1 suffix if needed.

```
$attr = 'thumbnail';
$new_file = ...; // absolute path to your file
$category = ...; // your category  model

$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS;
if (md5_file($new_file) != md5_file($path.$category->getData($attr)) {
    $ioObject = new Varien_Io_File();
    try {
        $ioObject->open(array('path'=>$path));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $ioObject->mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        $ioObject->open(array('path'=>$path));
    }
    $destFile = $path . Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader::getNewFileName($path . basename($new_file));
    $ioObject->cp($new_file, $destFile);
    $category->setData($attr, basename($destFile));
}
```